# Publish third party dll together with word 2013 add in

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm developing a word 2013 add in, which amongst other things, reads the data from personal ID card, inserted in card reader and once when it reads them it inserts them to the word document.

There is unmanaged dll, which communicates with the reader, and exposes API which can be applied. I have also created .NET wrapper DLL which accesses API calls through DllImport attributes and serves as the interface towards the unmanaged dll.

This .NET DLL is added as the reference to the word 2013 add in project.

Everything works fine, and the problem is, how to deliver the solution to the potential customer computer, all together with one installation program?

"Publish" option, which is available for the Office Add-In projects, don't offer the possibility to take third party dll, include it in the installation package and specify, where will it be copied on the client computer. Not at least that I have found it.

.NET library will be nevertheless the part of the installation package, because it is referenced in the add in project. But the unmanaged dll will not be copied. So we would have a shell without the content, and it won't work.

Is the including of the unmanaged dll as the embedded resource to the .NET dll a possible solution for this? I've seen some instructions here on forums of how to handle the embedded third party dll resource, and it seems a bit complicated.

Would there be an easier solution?

Thanks all in advance for the tipps!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in the meantime, while I was waiting for the answer, I've tried something for myself and it appears to be working.

It is actually very simple. The third party DLL, which is referred by the .NET wrapper DLL, should be included in add-in project as the content, which will be copied to the location of executable. Since the .NET wrapper DLL is also copied there, DLLImport("thirparty.dll") will do the work.